# How do I programmatically select an item in a listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, selection, highlight

I am displaying a radio schedule in a List View and would like to highlight the currently playing program.  I also want to allow the user to click on any program and get more details for the program.  I have tried the following:

```
radioView.setSelection(adapter.getCurrentProgramIndex());
radioView.setSelected(true);
```

This does scroll the list down to the selection which is good, but it does not highlight the selection.  I understand this is because [the device is not in touch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067456/android-listview-programmatic-selection-highlight), but how then would I go about highlighting the current program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how then would I go about highlighting
>   the current program?

Change something in that list row. For example, perhaps you have an icon you can switch to be a "playing" icon, or have an icon that is formerly `INVISIBLE` become `VISIBLE`, or something.

Bear in mind that you will need to have these smarts in your row binding code, so that if the user scrolls, you correct undo and redo that setting -- otherwise, row recycling will make it appear that other programs are playing.

Comment: Can I also change the background color?

Comment: Yes, but that gets tricky, so it does not interfere with the selector bar.